# asp.net webapi post method returns Object { _body: error, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: {…}, type: 3, url: null }

Tags: entity-framework, post, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am creating a web api with ef core - code first.

There is a one-to-one relationship of Website to HomeSection, and one-to-many of HomeSection with Paragraph (bridge with HomePara).

Here are my models:

```
public class Website
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string WebsiteUrl { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public HomeSection Home { get; set; }
}

public class HomeSection
{
    public HomeSection()
    {
        HomeParas = new HashSet<HomePara>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MinLength(3)]
    public string Header { get; set; }
    [MinLength(3)]
    public string BackgroundImageUrl { get; set; }
    public Boolean isActive { get; set; }

    public ICollection<HomePara> HomeParas { get; set; }

    public int WebsiteId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("WebsiteId")]
    public virtual Website website { get; set; }
}

public class HomePara
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int HomeId { get; set; }
    public int ParagraphId { get; set; }

    public HomeSection Home { get; set; }
    public Paragraph Para { get; set; }
}

public class Paragraph
{
    public Paragraph()
    {
        HomeParas = new HashSet<HomePara>();
    }
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public ICollection<HomePara> HomeParas { get; set; }
}
```

The post method of my Controller:
When the user create a website, I want to create a homesection and a paragraph by default.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Websites")]
[EnableCors("AllowAny")]
public class WebsitesController : Controller
{
    private readonly WebSiteContext _context;

    public WebsitesController(WebSiteContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostWebsite([FromBody] Website website)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        _context.Websites.Add(website);

        //create a default paragraph data and add it
        Paragraph newParagraph = new Paragraph()
        {
            Text = "Home Para"
        };
        _context.Paragraphs.Add(newParagraph);

        //create a default home data and add it
        HomeSection newhome = new HomeSection()
        {
            Header = website.Name + "Head",
            BackgroundImageUrl = website.Name + "bg url",
            WebsiteId = website.Id,
            isActive = true
        };
        _context.HomeSections.Add(newhome);

        //mapping home to para
        newhome.HomeParas.Add(new HomePara()
        {
            HomeId = newhome.Id,
            ParagraphId = newParagraph.Id
        });

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return CreatedAtAction("GetWebsite", new { id = website.Id }, website);
    }
}
```

This is returning `Object { _body: error, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: {…}, type: 3, url: null }` instead of `201 status`.

However the data is being saved, which I verified with the `get` request.

**EDIT:**
I have added the controller definition.

I noticed to peculiar things:

1. I put the whole code of post method inside a try catch and it executed without any errors. However, after the execution of return statement it is binding the `Website` property and when it hits the `HomeSection` of `HomePara` it fails for some reason is escapes the execution flow, and I get **0 status**.
2. Secondly, if I copy the original parameter of the post method `Website website` into another `Website` like below

   ```
   Website newWebsite = new Website() { Id = website.Id, Name = website.Name, WebsiteUrl = website.WebsiteUrl };
   ```

   and then pass this `newWebsite` to `CreatedAtAction()` method,

   ```
   return CreatedAtAction("GetWebsite", new { id = website.Id }, newWebsite);
   ```

   then I get the **201 status**. I don't know why this happens. How to solve this?

Comment: Are you saving and returning HTML as text?

Comment: no my controller is returning `CreatedAtActionResult` and I have `[Produces("application/json")]` attribute on my controller

Comment: Include the controller definition in the example provided as well.